# Build once, deploy many using gitflow and gitversion

Tags: git, git-flow, gitversion

The gitflow fits our needs and the giversion seems to be fitting the gitflow. But there is one thing which I don't fully understand. Let me explain what bothers me.

1. We do work on some functionality on develop branch - all the packages are marked like this 1.3.0-unstable.1, 1.3.0-unstable.2 and so on.
2. Every package is going though the pipeline - dev, test, uat, prod.
3. So when the dev is ready and everything is good, according to the gitflow we start the release branch.
4. No changes need to be done on release, we are finishing it right away - release branch merged into the master and into the develop.
5. Build server creates one more package 1.3.0 which is kind of prod ready.

How to achieve build once, deploy many here? According to all the rules, we need to promote 1.3.0-unstable.x to the prod env, cause exactly this package was tested in dev and test, but the version looks a bit strange for prod, isn't it? When 1.3.0 which came from master branch was never deployed anywhere.

Question is similar to this: [In the git flow model should I build from the merge commit in master to release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823250/in-the-git-flow-model-should-i-build-from-the-merge-commit-in-master-to-release)

The answer is not really satisfying:

1. We do -no-ff while merging to the master
2. It's still a different package

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but the point is this: The developers test the product on their feature branches and the develop branch. Once the software seems stable, a new release branch is made and the application is given to the QA team for more professional testing. If any bug comes out, you fix them in the release branch (and merge it back into develop). No additional features are allowed in the release branch. Once the testing is done, your chief can promote the release to the master branch for the sys admins to deploy.

Comment: @MargaretBloom this is exactly what we do. Let me extend my example. Like you said: we create a release branch and also after a couple of bugs, the version of the package will be 1.3.0-rc3. Again which package we should deploy to prod? The latest from QA? it has a strange name rc3, or the one generated from the master branch? But the package generated from master is not the same package as rc3 - here we break the rule: build once, deploy many.

Comment: I'm not an expert, so you are better off waiting for someone else; My understanding is that "Build once, Deploy many" means that you don't gives the QA team a source code to run in an IDE or the sys admins a source  to build, but rather you give them a built product. In your example, once you have fixed a bug, you rebuild from the sources and give the binary to QA and to the sys admins. If the QA clear the tests, the sys admins take the same build and deploy it.

Comment: @Max “But the package generated from master is not the same package as rc3” why do you say that? A merge commit in `master` is nothing more that a commit which points to 2 parents. Code wise, that merge commit in `master` still has the exact same contents as the one in the `release` branch, so the package generated in both is, for any practical measures, the same.

Comment: @HugoFerreira Yes and no! I do understand that they should be the same(the code supposed to be the same) but if I do build it one more time - those are different. I am speaking in the context of Octopus deployment pipelines:
https://octopus.com/blog/build-your-binaries-once

Comment: @Max ok, i see your point about the build runtime in that context, especially considering bundled libraries, etc. Then, can’t the 1.3.0-rc3 simply be _renamed_ to 1.3.0 (meaning “the candidate was approved”) and deploy that to prod? the binary is exactly the same, we’d be just talking about a name/version label pointing to the same bin. Does it make sense?

Comment: @hugo-ferreira since the original question surrounds the use of GitVersion as well, the binaries will not be exactly the same.  GitVersion will "stamp" the AssemblyInfo file with the asserted version numbers, which will be different between the release branch and the master branch.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I see… don’t know how gitversion works, but then it’s no longer a matter of “branches strategy” using gitflow but rather a matter of how gitversion links the version number to the binaries Maybe using a more generic build number or date (see point 10. of http://semver.org) instead of the “release candidate” (rc) expression/semantics, it would look less strange in prod?

Comment: @HugoFerreira this is actually quite a big discussion, that has lots of different parts.  For me, GitVersion and GitFlow work hand in hand.  As you move between the branches, creating hotfixes, releases and features, GitVersion is right there with you to correctly assert a sematic version for the current state. However, neither GitFlow or GitVersion work well, in my opinion, with the concept of build once deploy everywhere. i.e. with GitFlow, you can't deploy everywhere, until you merge into master.

Comment: @HugoFerreira I think you are right - I need to configure gitversion so that to have a generic version without pre-release suffix but with metadata instead(1.3.0+release, 1.2.1+hotfix). In this case, according to the semver the version is valid since the metadata is ignored.

Comment: @Max I feel that you perhaps answered your own question. Could you please elaborate (links, references etc) your last comment and post it as an answer? This is something that has vexed me since I started looking at the combo GitFlow+GitVersion+OctopusDeploy.

Comment: @8DH took me a while:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer this question myself. We came up to the point where we realised that supporting several versions/several environments using the gitflow is a huge burden. Hence we were looking for something simpler, which is [github flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/). Of course it didn't completely solve the original issue(build once - deploy many) for us, but this is how we partly solved it.

Our pipeline changed

from: dev -> test -> uat -> prod

to: dev -> test and then uat -> prod

So like I said before, we are using the github flow. Whenever we are working on the new feature, first - we create a branch *featurename* from latest master. Every build from this branch is versioned like this 1.3.0-featurename.1, 1.3.0-featurename.2 and so on.

Once developer finishes his implementation and does all the dev checks, these exact binaries go to the test environment for QA. After QA guys sign off this version, we are happy to push this through our second pipeline uat -> prod. We merge the pull request for the *featurename* branch and the build version we get afterwards, lets say: 1.3.1 goes to the uat environment. Once it's signed off there, we push exactly the same binaries to the prod environment.

If there were several feature branches being developed at the same time, the next version we push to the test environment supposed to be rebased on top of the latest master and again through the pipeline.

Comment: so, it is build twice, once for dev and test and once for uat and prod?